# How to execute synchronously using setInterval or setTimeOut?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout, setinterval

I have a function as below:

```
function foo(args1, args2, retry)
{
    if (retry <= 0)
        return false;

    var isDone = callAnotherFunction(args1, args2);

    if(!isDone) {
       setInterval(function () {
           foo(args1, args2, retry-1);
       },
       2000);
    }
    else
      return true;
}
```

So I am not sure if the above implementation is correct. But I need to use this function in another function. And use the above function in an if block to decide if the other statement needs to be executed. Below is the usage of the above function.

```
function useIt(args1, args2)
{
    // Other code
    let store = function() {
       if(!foo(args1, args2, 5)) {
           cleanStorage(args1, args2);
           return;
       }
}
```

So the problem is in function `useIt()`, `cleanStorage()` does not wait for `foo()` to be executed if I am using `setInterval` or `setTimeOut`. So how do I need to implement the function `foo()` ? Kindly help me.

Comment: Why do you need to wait (using `setInterval`)?

Comment: I am using `setInterval` where I can retry in case of a failure and add a delay between the retries.

Comment: Although you've said "synchronously " in your title, I would have a look at making the function `foo` a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that way you can wait for a result from `foo` in the `useIt` function

Comment: I am not sure why there is a downvote since I could not find any duplicates for my question. Please add a comment as to why the question is downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) to do this

Something like this:

```
function foo(args1, args2, retry)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (retry <= 0)
        reject();

    var isDone = callAnotherFunction(args1, args2);

    if(!isDone) {
       setInterval(function () {
            retry = retry - 1;
            isDone = callAnotherFunction(args1, args2);
            if (isDone)
               resolve();
       },
       2000);
    }
    else
      resolve();
  }
}

function useIt(args1, args2)
{
    // Other code
    let store = function() {
    foo(args1, args2, 5).then(result => {
            cleanStorage(args1, args2);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

consider using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

foo can be rewritten like this (I've replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`):

```
function foo(args1, args2, retry) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (retry <= 0)
      reject();

    var isDone = callAnotherFunction(args1, args2);

    if (!isDone) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        resolve(foo(args1, args2, retry - 1));
      }, 2000);
    }
    else
      resolve(true);
  })
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
function useIt(args1, args2) {
  // Other code
  let store = function () {
    foo(args1, args2, 5).then(function () {
      cleanStorage(args1, args2);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If foo does return a promise, `!foo(…)` will always be false. You need to actually wait for the promise using `.then` or `await`.

Comment: But the `reject` is never being used.

Comment: @SuhasKulkarni I've edited the code to show how reject can be used.